# Expand and filter nested lookup fields

Tags: lookup-column

Lets suppose this structure below:

[image]

Is there any way to select children whom have `root/Id eq 1` with REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Not in a single call. You can't do nested expands for relationships based on lookup fields.